# Cascade json property value to all descendants that are null using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I have been banging my head on this for far too long.  This is what I have:

Source:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Item A",
    "parent": "",
    "team": "Team 1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Item B",
    "parent": "Item A",
    "team": "Team 2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Item C",
    "parent": "Item A",
    "team": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Item D",
    "parent": "Item C",
    "team": null
  }
]
```

JQ Command:

```
def func($p): select(.name==$p) | (.team // func(.parent)); map(.team = (.team // func(.parent)))
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Item A",
    "parent": "",
    "team": "Team 1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Item B",
    "parent": "Item A",
    "team": "Team 2"
  }
]
```

What I want is for both items with a null team to inherit their team value from the their parent.  If their parent's team is null look at their parents parent and so on.  In the above example team would be "Team 1" for both Item C and Item D.  If Item C has a parent of Item B then Items C and D should have a parent of "Team 2".

This is a simplified example and may contain several items with null teams that need to inherit from a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a recursive function to "fill-in" the dictionary constructed by `INDEX(.[]; .name)`:

```py
# $ix to handle the case of no parent having a team
def team($name; $ix):
  if $name == null or $ix == 0 then null
  else .[$name].team // team(.[$name].parent; $ix-1)
  end;
  
INDEX(.[]; .name) 
| reduce keys_unsorted[] as $k (.; .[$k].team = team($k; length))
| [.[]]
```

Comment: This works perfectly with source given above but will fail if "Item A" has a null .team.  If there is no .team found using recursion it should default to null.  << I apologize, another missed requirement.

Comment: Updated to handle such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: this is a response to the original question.

You could use `first/1`, e.g.:

```py
first(.[] | (.team // empty)) as $default
| map( .team |= (. // $default) )
```

Comment: Thank you @peak for educating about first and therefore, last and nth.  The solution did meet the requirement perfectly as written, unfortunately, I didn't articulate my requirements clearly.  I updated the question to describe the requirements better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I needed to send a reference to the original collection to prevent `select` from filtering the items.  This is what I cam up with:

```
def func($collection; $parent): 
    if $parent == null or $parent == "" then 
        null 
    else $collection 
        | .[] 
        | select(.name==$parent)
        | .team // func($collection; .parent)
    end;  
        
. as $collection
    | map(.team = (.team // func($collection; .parent)))
```